# Why do we need Parent Node in Binary Search Tree - C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I have only started learning Data Structures so please bear my stupidity, I am trying to develop my own version of BST, I can't get why there is a need of a parent Node? Shouldn't this work just fine.

```
class BST 
{
    private Node root;

    public BST()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public void insert(int value) 
    {
        Node temp = new Node();
        temp.value = value;

        if (root == null)
        {
            root = temp;
            return;
        }

        Node current = root;

        while (current != null) 
        {
            if (value <= current.value)
            {
                current = current.lc;
            }
            else 
            {
                current = current.rc;
            }
        }

        current = temp;
    }
}

class Node
{
    public Node lc;
    public int value;
    public Node rc;
}
```

There is definitely something that I am missing and I can't grasp or get what it is, when current is null, we are already onto where we need to insert the node, why then do we need a parent node.

Comment: What do you mean by "need"?

Comment: I can't correctly understand what you don't missing is. Can you tell it more elaborately?

Comment: Umm V0ldek, I don't get you...From I've learned we need a Node that points the parent of Node we're going to insert.

Comment: does the code above that I am writing for creating a BST is valid for insert function?

Comment: No, it's not. `current = temp;` does nothing useful, just assigns local variable. In order to do actual insert, `temp` must be assigned to either `parent.lc` or `parent.rc`.

Comment: But isn't current already pointing to left child or the right child where the new nodes need to be inserted.

Comment: BST revers to a tree which has nodes and node leaves, it is a tree. How you want to call them is up to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Answer (score 0):

You are setting "null" to some instance.

In your while loop current eventually becomes null, and you are missing the connection between nodes.

To fix this issue you should keep the last node of your tree.

You can try the below :

```
class BST
{
    private Node root;

    public BST()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public void insert(int value)
    {
        root = insert(root, value);
    }

    private Node insert(Node node, int value) {
        // if the given node is null it should be new node
        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node();
            node.value = value;
            return node;
        }

        if (value < node.value)
            // if our value lower then current value then we will insert left node recursively
            node.lc = insert(node.lc, value);
        else if (value > node.value)
            // if our value higher then current value then we will insert right node recursively
            node.rc = insert(node.rc, value);

        return node;
    }

    public void print() {
        print(root);
    }

    private void print(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            print(node.lc);
            Console.WriteLine(node.value);
            print(node.rc);
        }
        return;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    BST bst = new BST();

    bst.insert(5);
    bst.insert(25);
    bst.insert(15);
    bst.insert(4);

    bst.print();
}
```

The output is :

```
4
5
15
25
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
class BST
{
    private Node root = null;

    public void insert(int value)
    {
        Node temp = new Node { value = value };

        if (root == null)
        {
            root = temp;
            return;
        }

        var current = root;

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (value <= current.value)
            {
                if (current.lc == null)
                {
                    current.lc = temp; 
                    break;
                }
                current = current.lc;
            }
            else
            {
                if (current.rc == null)
                {
                    current.rc = temp; 
                    break;
                }
                current = current.rc;
            }
        }

    }
}

class Node
{
    public Node lc;
    public int value;
    public Node rc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing variables with references to fields/variables. The `current` variable holds the *value* of the `lc` or `rc` field (the copy of the field). Setting the variable does not set the corresponding field, just assigns another value to the variable.

Hence the line

```
current = temp;
```

does not insert the node in the BST.

What you are trying to do is possible with C#7.0 introduced [ref locals and returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#ref-locals-and-returns) and C#7.3 introduced [improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3) which allow to reassign ref local variables.

The ref local variables are exactly what is your intention - they contain the location (reference, address) of some other field / variable. So the following works (requires C#7.3!):

```
public void insert(int value)
{
    ref Node nodeRef = ref root;
    while (nodeRef != null)
    {
        if (value <= nodeRef.value)
            nodeRef = ref nodeRef.lc;
        else
            nodeRef = ref nodeRef.rc;
    }
    nodeRef = new Node { value = value };
}
```

Note the usage of `ref` keyword. You use `nodeRef = ref …` to assign a reference (address) of a variable (in this case either `root` or some node `lc` or `rc` field), and `nodeRef = …` to assign a value to the variable pointed by the `nodeRef`.